# .htaccess Internal Server Error

Tags: php, htaccess, apache

Quero deixar minhas URLs mais amigáveis e estou utilizando o `.htaccess` para isso.

O problema é que está me retornando um Internal Server Error, e não consegui identificar onde está o erro da minha Rule.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^autenticar/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?& index?authUser=$1
```

Obtenho ISE ao acessar a url: `http://localhost/autenticar/teste/`,
mas consigo acessar `http://localhost/index` sem problema algum.

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Se eu remover a linha que adiciona .php no final dos arquivos, recebo "objeto não encontrado".

Se eu adiciono `[NC, L]`, recebo outro ISE, com esta mensagem:

> "O servidor encontrou um erro interno e não foi possível completar sua
>   requisição. O servidor está sobrecarregado ou existe um erro em um
>   script CGI."

Estou usando o Xampp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao colocar a regra mais generica primeiro (`RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]`) você obterá um loop infinito caso o arquivo requisitado pela url não exista. Por exemplo, se você requisitar a url `http://localhost/autenticar/teste`, do jeito que o seu htaccess está (`RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]` como primeira regra) será feito um redirecionamento para  `http://localhost/autenticar/teste.php` (já que a regra pega a uri e concantena .php). Mas se o arquivo (`/autentica/teste.php`) não existir a regra será chamada novamente, gerando um loop. A solução é colocá-la por ultimo. Com as correções o .htacess fica assim (Observe os comentários #):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# procura pela uri autentica/teste ou autentica/teste/, ou seja com 
# ou sem a barra final ([/]{0,1} caso exista nenhuma ou uma barra)
# a flag QSA adiciona os parametros get, caso exisam, da url original
# para a nova url. Algo como autentica/teste?a=1&b=2 fica 
# index.php?authUser=teste&a=1&b=2
RewriteRule ^autenticar/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)[/]{0,1} index.php?authUser=$1 [QSA,L]

# para evitar que a próxima regra seja executada caso exista algum match na
# primeira
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

Utilizando:

- `http://localhost/autenticar/teste/` fica `http://localhost/index.php?authUser=teste`
- `http://localhost/autenticar/teste/?a=1&b=2` fica `http://localhost/index.php?authUser=teste&a=1&b=2`
- `http://localhost/autenticar/teste?a=1&b=2` fica `http://localhost/index.php?authUser=teste&a=1&b=2`
- `http://localhost/pagina1` fica `http://localhost/pagina1.php`, mas caso pagina1.php não exista será exibido o erro de internal server, pois irá gerar um loop (como o arquivo não existe será feito um novo redirecionamento).

Leitura recomendada:

- [Um guia rápido de comando com htaccess](http://www.aboutonlinematters.com/2009/09/htaccess-grammar-tutorial-special-characters/)
- [FastRoute](https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute) um framework para criar rotas de uma maneira mais 'simples'